# How can I exclude Javascript files so as to ignore the warning "ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in"?

Tags: command-line, ctags

Is there any way I can hide the `ctags: Warning: ignoring null tag in` warning from prointing on the shell when I execute `ctags` in the `src/`? All of these warning seem to refer to `.js` files which is out of scope for me. I'm working with `.c` files under the hood but they are in thesame top level directory (`src/`) and I run the following command: `ctags -R *;cscope -R` from `src/` in order to browse the existing code but I get all these messages from a directories I don't "care" about.

Comment: So rather than use `*` which will include all the `.js` files throwing the warning, why not just use `*.c` (or `*.cpp`, etc.) to only run `ctags` on the C code, thereby avoiding the warning in the first place?

Comment: because there's no source files in `src/` itself, all sources are within subdirectories...

Comment: Try `--exclude='*.js'`, which some versions of ctags support.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that's it! You can add your comment as an answer and i'll accept! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you give ctags the `-R` (recurse) option, it's often useful to use the `--exclude` option to tell it to ignore things like source control directories or files you're not interested in indexing.

In your case, use the option `--exclude='*.js'` .

Comment: If you are using `~/.ctags` or `.ctags.d/example.ctag` in your current working directory, this works, but you need to omit the single quotes from `--exclude='*.js'`, as this is a shell feature. Instead, include `--exclude=*.js`

Comment: no, actually you need the quotes, as you DON'T want the shell to expand the *.